# How to set up a Git server with HTTP access on Linux

Tags: linux, git, http

I need to create a Git repository on a Linux machine and then make it accessible via HTTP. Also need full access with one user and read-only to anon-users.

I've created local repositories before but I don't know how to create this (e.g.: inside /var/www or /opt/git/...)

I tried doing this:

> -sudo Clone a GitHub repository into /var/www/repos/repo.git
>   -cd /var/www/repos/repo.git
>   -sudo git --bare update-server-info
>   -sudo mv hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update
>   -sudo service apache2 restart

Then I tried to access this repository from another machine:

> -With browser : (http protocol)192.168.1.49/repo.git <-- WORKS
>   -With terminal: git clone --bare (http protocol)192.168.1.49/repo.git <--DOESN'T WORK

The terminal says:

> Cloning into bare repository repo.git...
>   fatal: (http protocol)192.168.1.49/repo.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

I think maybe it's a permissions problem. How I need to manage permissions inside /var/www?

EDIT: Already fixed, just needed:

> -put the repository into /var/www/repos/ named repo.git
>   -change the permissions of the www folder with sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
>   -enable webdav with sudo a2enmod dav_fs
>   -config file into /etc/apache2/conf.d called git.conf
>   -create the file with users with sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/passwd.git user
>   -rename the pot-update file and make it executable with sudo mv /var/www/repos/repo.git/hooks/post-update.sample /var/www/repos/repo.git/hooks/post-update && sudo chmod a+x /var/www/repos/repo.git/hooks/post-update
>   -update server and restart apache with sudo git update-server-info && sudo service apache2 restart

And, to fix the problem with pushing:

> Edit the file .git/config into your repository folder (client machine) and put the username and password on the url:
>   url = (http protocol)user:password@url/repos/repo.git

So, now only I need is to set the read-only for anon-users.

Comment: Why are you using sudo?

Comment: @AD7six don't know, just following an internet tutorial...

Comment: This is not a programming question, so it's off-topic.

Comment: if you're wanting to setup write access over http - that's off topic for stack overflow. If you use sudo - you will get permission problems, since everything's owned by root. "normally" you'd setup http for readonly, anon access and use ssh for read/write - which is easy to setup too

Comment: @AD7six Yes i'm agree with you, but this is a school homework so we need to read/write with http.

Comment: time to learn to ask questions in the right place then =) flagging to migrate to server fault (though you'll probably find [existing questions](http://serverfault.com/search?q=git+webdav) solve your problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already fixed, just needed:

> -put the repository into /var/www/repos/ named repo.git
>
> -change the permissions of the www folder with sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
>
> -enable webdav with sudo a2enmod dav_fs
>
> -config file into /etc/apache2/conf.d called git.conf
>
> -create the file with users with sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/passwd.git user
>
> -rename the pot-update file and make it executable with sudo mv /var/www/repos/repo.git/hooks/post-update.sample
>
> /var/www/repos/repo.git/hooks/post-update && sudo chmod a+x
>
> /var/www/repos/repo.git/hooks/post-update
>
> -update server and restart apache with sudo git update-server-info && sudo service apache2 restart

And, to fix the problem with pushing:

> Edit the file .git/config into your repository folder (client machine)
>
> and put the username and password on the url: url = (http
>
> protocol)user:password@url/repos/repo.git

So, now only I need is to set the read-only for anon-users.